# SQL select latest values in a many-to-many table

Tags: sql, select, group-by, pivot-table

How can I select latest records in a a table with many-to-many relationship. The store_id,product_id is not a composite group key so they repeat many times.

```
id store_id product_id
1     1         1
2     2         1  
3     1         1
4     3         1
5     2         1
6     3         1
```

The result should be like this:

```
id store_id product_id

3     1         1
5     2         1
6     3         1
```

For the sake of simplicity I only added 1 product but in the real case there are many products. So the result should be something like :
For each store_id show the latest added products_id.

e.g.

```
id store_id product_id

11     1         1
20     1         2
40     1         3
41     1         4
53     2         1
61     2         2
62     2         3
63     2         4
70     3         1
71     3         2
72     3         3
73     3         4
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what this has to do with a pivot table.  This seems like a basic aggregation:

```
select max(id) as id, store_id, product_id
from t
group by store_id, product_id
order by store_id, max(id);
```

Comment: I edited the question it is not necessarily a pivot table.

Comment: @Victordb . . . This type of table is often called a junction or association table.  It is used to implement many-to-many relationships.